# How to configure Dual Touch on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-touch, qt, multi-touch, touchscreen

Is there something that I need to configure on Ubuntu to recognize dual touch points on my application?

- I am developing a Qt application on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine which has touchscreen monitor (which supports Dual Touch).
- However, my application is only able to detect one touch point. I want to configure my touchscreen to be able to recognize two concurrent touch points (say with two fingers) so that I can develop pinch to zoom sort of handling on my Qt application.
- When I built the same Qt application for Android platform, the dual touch points works fine.

Thanks in advance for any help.